# Web App with Google Script reads Gsheet Speed Optimization

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I made a simple web app with GS and now need to optimize the speed of loading data from a Gsheet. Description of the app:

It is a tool to collect the correct colors of a product in an image.
When user clicks on load image button, the app will read the URL from a Gsheet where all the tasks are stored in rows and load the image. User then select colors from a palette and submit colors. Then the app will save the selected color values to the same row of the image URL.

Each task should be assigned to n users (no more no less, feedbackRequested as below) to avoid bias and the same task should not be assigned to the same user more than once. So I stored the tasks in this way:

```
index   imageID      URL   feedbackRequested   user   rgb_value
 1      104904677    ***          3                            
 2      104904677    ***          3                            
 3      104904677    ***          3  
 4      104904678    ***          2                           
 5      104904678    ***          2
```

I spread n `feedbackRequested` to n rows to assign the tasks. So when a user clicks on load image, the following will be executed:

1. get an array with all imageIDs this user has done;

```
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,2,sheet.getLastRow(),4).getValues();
  var filter_user = ArrayLib.filterByText(data, 3, user);
  var user_imageIDs = filter_user.map(function(value,index) {return value[0]});
```

2. if imageID is in the array or user is not empty, continue looking until we find the row;

```
var ct = 1;
while ( (user_imageIDs.includes(data[ct][0])) || (data[ct][3] != '') ) {
    ct++;
  };
```

3. set the user value to the user on this row and save his answer to rgb_value.

```
sheet.getRange(ct+1, 5,1,2).setValues(user, somevalue);
```

This way it takes a lot of time to find the conditioned row with while loop. Is there other ways to do this?

I know this is a lot of information. Thanks very much in advance! Please let me know if you need the entire code to reproduce.

Comment: Are the ``imageID``s always in ascending order?

Comment: no that's totally arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of imageIDs which contain `usr`:

```
const imageSet = data.reduce((s,[id,_,_,usr])=> 
    usr === user ? s.add(id) : s,
  new Set)
```

- Use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the index of  `data` array, where `usr` is empty  and id is not in imageSet:

```
const ct = data.findIndex(([id,_,_,usr])=> usr === "" && !imageSet.has(id))
```

Comment: The ```imageSet``` i got is an empty set. so ```data``` I have here (not like in the example) has actually 2 columns ```imageID``` and ```user```. anything wrong?

Comment: @Gwen You should modify the "destructuring assignment"([id,_,_,usr]) accordingly.

Comment: I did that already, removed ```,_,_```  and got an empty set. findIndex is faster than the while loop it seems if I use ```const ct = data.findIndex(([id,usr])=> usr === "" && (!user_imageIDs.includes(id)))```

Comment: I am also wondering if there's another completely different approach than finding the row that meets the conditions, that enhances the speed significantly?

Comment: @gwen what makes you think they're empty?

Comment: Hi! I checked the log. imageSet is {}.

Comment: @gwen `Sets` cannot be logged. They're not stringifiable.  You can check the size `console.info(imageSet.size)` or convert them to a array to log: `console.info([...imageSet])`(Although looks simple, it's a full for loop there...)

Comment: right! Now the size is correct. before somehow it ignored the fact that this task had been done by this user so I thought it was indeed empty. but now it's all working. The speed improved 3-5 seconds per load. Thanks a lot!